# Ansible lineinfile module not adding all the required lines to the file

Tags: ansible

I am using lineinfile module in ansible to append all the hosts in inventory to a file.
This is the ansible playbook code -

```
- hosts: test
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - name: Create file to store hosts to be updated
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      file:
        path: /tmp/updated_hosts.txt
        state: touch
        mode: u=rw,g=rw,o=rw

    - name: WRITE of updated hosts in play
      delegate_to: localhost
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/updated_hosts.txt
        line: "{{ inventory_hostname }},"
      when: some condition
```

This is my inventory

```
[test]
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
test9
test10
test11
test12
test13
test14
test15
test16
test17
test18
test19
test20
test21
test22
test23
test24
test25
test26
test27
test28
test29
test30
```

But after running the playbook

```
PLAY [test] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Create file to store hosts to be updated] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [test1 -> localhost]

TASK [WRITE of updated hosts in play] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [test2 -> localhost]
changed: [test1 -> localhost]
changed: [test4 -> localhost]
changed: [test5 -> localhost]
changed: [test3 -> localhost]
changed: [test7 -> localhost]
changed: [test10 -> localhost]
changed: [test6 -> localhost]
changed: [test8 -> localhost]
changed: [test9 -> localhost]
changed: [test11 -> localhost]
changed: [test12 -> localhost]
changed: [test13 -> localhost]
changed: [test14 -> localhost]
changed: [test15 -> localhost]
changed: [test16 -> localhost]
changed: [test18 -> localhost]
changed: [test20 -> localhost]
changed: [test19 -> localhost]
changed: [test17 -> localhost]
changed: [test21 -> localhost]
changed: [test24 -> localhost]
changed: [test22 -> localhost]
changed: [test23 -> localhost]
changed: [test25 -> localhost]
changed: [test26 -> localhost]
changed: [test29 -> localhost]
changed: [test27 -> localhost]
changed: [test28 -> localhost]
changed: [test30 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
test1                      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test10                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test11                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test12                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test13                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test14                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test15                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test16                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test17                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test18                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test19                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test2                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test20                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test21                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test22                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test23                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test24                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test25                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test26                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test27                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test28                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test29                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test3                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test30                     : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test4                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test5                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test6                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test7                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test8                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test9                      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

when I check the content of /tmp/updated_hosts.txt this is what I find -

```
test1,
test5,
test3,
test8,
test9,
test14,
test17,
test22,
test25,
test30,
```

Why am I not able to see all hosts ? Even though I see that the task has been executed on all the hosts.

P.S. - the hosts in inventory test1, test2 ... are just for the purpose of question.

EDIT - I have edited the ansible code to only write the hostname to the file when it satisfies some condition

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/f4c33009b8782873ca165d6d3747f357)

Comment: Moreover, updating a file on the go is not the best way to do this. You can get that list at once at the end of the play in the `ansible_play_host` [magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

Comment: @Zeitounator just for the purpose of asking the question I have formatted what I wanted to achieve. The thing is I dont want every host to be written in the file but only those hosts which satisfy the condition which I will put in the when statement

Comment: @ashishpm then don't put that in a when statement and filter the `hostvars` dictionary with `selectattr`. You need to explain us what you really want to do, and not your current attempt, or you'll face the dreaded [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue could be caused by multiple hosts trying to update the file at the same time. There is chance of missing some lines.
Try to loop over the hosts using the [`with_inventory_hostnames` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/inventory_hostnames_lookup.html)

```yaml
    - name: WRITE of updated hosts in play
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/updated_hosts.txt
        line: "{{ item }},"
        insertafter: EOF
      with_inventory_hostnames:
        - test
```

Comment: I have edited the question to change the code to only insert the hostname to the file when it satisfies some condition

Comment: add `insertafter: EOF`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following logic it's worked in my code:

```
  - name: tracking
    lineinfile:
      path: /path/file_name.txt
      line: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
      state: present
      insertafter: EOF
    register: check
    retries: 1
    until: check is not changed
    when: Some condition 
    delegate_to: localhost
    ignore_errors: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the underlying problem is, that you task with `lineinfile` is only running on localhost and you run 30 threads at the same time to change a single file on a single system.

Then of course, the `lineinfile` module on one thread overrides the already written data in another thread. Because the system isn't verifying its output you get random "race-condition-like" output. You could try this by adding a "serial: 1" to the playbook.

```
- hosts: test
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    ...
```